# SQL case giving error while using substring

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am facing an error while using a SQL Server `CASE` statement with a `SUBSTRING` function call:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT 
     sys.Netbios_Name0, sys.name0, sys.Operating_System_Name_and0,
     sys.AD_Site_Name0, sys1.DisplayName0, sys1.Version0,
     sys2.TopConsoleUser0, sys3.model0,
     CASE sys.Operating_System_Name_and0
        WHEN SUBSTRING(sys.Operating_System_Name_and0, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', sys.Operating_System_Name_and0), sys.Operating_System_Name_and0) = '6.3' 
           THEN 'Windows 8' 
        WHEN SUBSTRING(sys.Operating_System_Name_and0, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', sys.Operating_System_Name_and0), sys.Operating_System_Name_and0) = '6.2' 
           THEN 'Windows 8' 
        WHEN SUBSTRING(sys.Operating_System_Name_and0, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', sys.Operating_System_Name_and0), sys.Operating_System_Name_and0) = '6.1'  
           THEN 'Windows 7' 
        WHEN SUBSTRING(sys.Operating_System_Name_and0, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', sys.Operating_System_Name_and0), sys.Operating_System_Name_and0) = '6.0'  
           THEN 'Windows Vista' 
        WHEN SUBSTRING(sys.Operating_System_Name_and0, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', sys.Operating_System_Name_and0), sys.Operating_System_Name_and0) = '5.2' 
           THEN 'Windows XP' 
        WHEN SUBSTRING(sys.Operating_System_Name_and0, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', sys.Operating_System_Name_and0), sys.Operating_System_Name_and0) = '5.0' 
           THEN 'Windows 2000' 
        ELSE 'sys.Netbios_Name0' 
     END AS WindowsVersion
FROM
    fn_rbac_Add_Remove_Programs(1) sys1 
INNER JOIN  
    v_r_system sys ON sys.ResourceID = sys1.ResourceID  
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM sys3 ON sys1.ResourceID = sys3.ResourceID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    v_GS_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USAGE_MAXGROUP sys2 ON sys.Resourceid = sys2.ResourceID 
-- WHERE sys1.DisplayName0 LIKE '%' + @prodname + '%' AND sys1.version0 LIKE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @variable) + '%'
```

I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

Am I doing something wrong? Please let me know

Comment: Using `sys` as an alias seems like a bad idea, as it's a schema in every database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the two possible syntax options for the `case` expression.

One being:

```
CASE input_expression   
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ]   
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ]   
END
```

and the other being:

```
CASE  
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ]   
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ]   
END
```

You can use either the first or the second, but not both in the same `case` expression.

Since all the expressions in your `when` parts are
`sys.SUBSTRING(sys.Operating_System_Name_and0, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', sys.Operating_System_Name_and0), sys.Operating_System_Name_and0) = <some value>`, your case expression can be written using the first option:

```
 CASE sys.SUBSTRING(sys.Operating_System_Name_and0, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', sys.Operating_System_Name_and0), sys.Operating_System_Name_and0)
    WHEN '6.3' 
       THEN 'Windows 8' 
    WHEN '6.2' 
       THEN 'Windows 8' 
    WHEN '6.1'  
       THEN 'Windows 7' 
    WHEN '6.0'  
       THEN 'Windows Vista' 
    WHEN '5.2' 
       THEN 'Windows XP' 
    WHEN '5.0' 
       THEN 'Windows 2000' 
    ELSE 'sys.Netbios_Name0' 
 END AS WindowsVersion
```

Answer (score 0):

`sys.Operating_System_Name_and0` after case is redundent. so case statement should be like

```
SELECT ...
CASE /*comment col name here*/
WHEN substring(...) = ...
....
```